# Slack - How to add a person to a group chat including the chat's history?

Tags: slack, chat

I'm chatting with a few coworkers on slack and would like to add another coworker to the chat.

The problem is that when I add a new coworker to the group chat, a new group chat is created without the history.

Is there a way to add a person to a group chat including the chat's history?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/212281468-Direct-messages-and-group-DMs ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180603213420/https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/212281468-Direct-messages-and-group-DMs)):

> When you add people to a DM (Direct Message), a new conversation will start without the previous message history. (If you'd like to keep message history, you can [move the group DM to a private channel](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/217555437) instead.)

Comment: Correct but unsatisfactory answer. Good tip about private channels, thanks.

Comment: Have to agree. This is annoyingly unsatisfactory given how long Slack has known that this is unacceptable.

Comment: @gravidThoughts annoyingly unsatisfactory is my whole slack experience.

Comment: so sad, it's true

Comment: It must be to prevent accidental sharing of secrets. Suppose Slack's engineers "fix" it. Alice and Bob chat in fixed-Slack from time to time, sometimes discussing sensitive issues that Charlie shouldn't read. (I'd argue that Alice and Bob shouldn't use any electronic communication in such cases.) One day in fixed-Slack, Alice and Bob discuss the upcoming group luncheon. Alice invites Charlie to the same chat to ask him what he wants for lunch. Charlie orders lunch and then scrolls back and reads the sensitive information that Alice and Bob didn't want him to see.

Comment: It would be useful to have a checkbox to allow or not allow new members to view the scrollback.  That is the behavior for private channels.